# RuntimeException:The "-r" option does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cmd, composer-php

I use *`php artisan make:model Reciveditem -mr`* for my larvel project. But command prompt was given this result -> *`[RuntimeException] The "-r" option does not exist`*.
I knew this is a composer issue but I don't know how to slove it.

I want to create a Model with Migration, Controller and generate DB Table. therefor I used `php artisan make:model Reciveditem -mr` code.

```
F:\laravel project\12test>php artisan make:model Reciveditem -mr
```

```
[RuntimeException] The "-r" option does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a model and additionally a controller and a migration table you need the parameter `-mc`.

In your case this would be:

```
php artisan make:model Reciveditem -mc
```

Comment: I tried this command but it didn't work. it was given this error   [RuntimeException]
  The "-c" option does not exist.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? I use this command every time I create new models and controllers so it should definitely work.

Comment: 5.1 version of laravel

Comment: Well I think this is the problem. Your laravel version is way to old! Why arent't you using a recent version like 6.0 or 5.5 (both with LTS)?

Comment: Because it is a running project yet. But  I want to do some changes in it.

Comment: I think those parameters aren't available in v. 5.1 of laravel so you need to create the controller manually. I would advice you to upgrade laravel to the next LTS version like 5.5 for security reasons. You will find some very good upgrade guides on the official laravel page.